# Clutch pedal starter

Tags: starting

Project on i10 car clutch pedal starter.
I would love to modify my car to only start the engine WHEN CLUTCH PEDAL IS PRESSED FULLY TO GROUND AND KEY IS AT START POSITION. (Eg. as in Hyundai Getz!!!)

Following points are considered....

1. Engine should be start only when clutch is depressed and key at start position.
2. As soon as engine is running, regardless of whether clutch is depressed or key engaged at start position, there should not be any current flowing to each relays. This is to prevent the STARTER MOTOR from double starting while ENGINE IS STILL LIVE and saves the MOTOR!!!
3. The above point 2 is controlled by relay which is powered from engine running.

Also, will the proposed diagram work in case if the car needs RUNNING START??

Waiting for your valuable comments and suggestions referring to points wise, thanks!!![image]

Comment: Auto manufacturers have been doing this for years ... they call it a "neutral safety switch".

Comment: This is true ..the system is actually built into almost every car but most times the system is just deactivated..but present..almost all cars now have clutch switches so wouldn't be hard to have an inhibitor wired in..but might already be there but disabled..

Comment: Now, found some fuses corresponding to this ignition starting system as picture attached herewith. Not sure, which one is yet.

Can I extend pin 30 of relay normal 12 v 5 pins to the positive side of those fuses which corresponds to ignition start power and another to pin 87. This relay is then connect in such a way that when clutch is fully depressed, relay is activated which would eventually allow current to start engine when key at start position.

If the above assumptions are correct, any issues or problems in future if keep continue to use this new system??